# Oracle Apex 5: Redirecting Branch after submit not working just refreshing page, why so?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a branch with PL/SQL function body code that checks to see if the login count is 0 or 1. If it is 1 then send the user to the homepage. Unfortunately, after I press the submit button it refreshes the page rather than following the branch and redirecting user to said page. How would you redirect a user depending on certain conditions? Any advice or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. My branch was overcomplicated with pl/sql and redirection code within it. I separated my validation into a process/validation process and kept the branch to a very simple redirect to page within app. I will, for future reference, keep my validation separate from my branch unless I can figure out a way to have them work together properly. Thank you all.